# Why sed script is not deleting lines?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

The following is my sed script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -r 's/^\s+?\/\/.*$/d/;
s/LOG.debug/System.out.println/g' "$1"
```

What the first command should do is delete all lines beginning with `//` preceded by any number of spaces or tabs. The only problem is instead of deleting those lines, it replaces them with a literal 'd'.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to remove the matching lines, you should not use the `s` command.

Use

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*\/\//d; s/LOG\.debug/System.out.println/g' "$1"
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, note that to match a literal dot, you need to escape it, hence, `LOG\.debug`.

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/rsLSFC).